# Use python 2.7 on mac osx using macports

Tags: python, macports

```
usge:~ glab$ port select --list python
Available versions for python:
    none (active)
    python25-apple
    python26-apple
    python27
usge:~ glab$ sudo port select --set python python27
Selecting 'python27' for 'python' failed: symlink: /opt/local/etc/select/python/current -> python27: file already exists


usge:~ glab$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
```

I want to set python2.7 as my default python, but am failing with error message above. How to fix this (I am using macports on mac osx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this before, but I can't recall how this issue occurs. The solution I believe is as simple as deleting the symlink referenced in the error and doing the port select command again.